# Как оставить письмо в одной папке Outlook

Tags: outlook

У меня в `Outlook` стоит правило, что письма, которые направлены в `Рассылка` класть в `Папка1`.

Также в `Рассылка` поступают письма, в которых в теле письма есть `Слово`.

Я бы хотел, чтобы письма, в которых в теле письма содержится `Слово`, клались только в `Папка2` и написал соответствующе правило. В итоге у меня эти письма ложатся и в `Папка1` и в `Папка2` (то есть дублируются из-за того что срабатывают параллельно эти два правила)

Как можно написать правило, чтобы эти письма клались только в `Папка2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо в первом правиле (которое перемещает письма направленные на `Рассылка` в `Папка1`), добавить условие "кроме содержащих `Слово` в тексте сообщения". В таком случае сообщения не дублируются

Answer (score 1):

Убрать правило, которое перемещает в  `Рассылка` письма, в теле которых есть `Слово`.

Или

Передвинуть второе правило выше первого и поставить галочку "не выполнять другие правила" (не помню как точно называется).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ: 1) В том то и дело такого правила нет, есть только правильно что класть все письма, которые поступили в `Рассылка` в `Папка1`, 2) А как можно такое прописать? Я в правилах видел только пункт "Если присутствует слово `Слово`, а чтобы с отрицанием было такого нет, или как так сделать можно? 3. Вроде как пока единственный вариант, надо попробовать

Comment: да, второй опции действительно нет.  1) А как тогда письма со ``Слово`` попадают в ``Рассылка``?

Comment: Поскольку это письмо направлено в `Рассылка` срабатывает первое правило